# Jolt update all 0 value to 1

Tags: json, jolt

I would like to know in Jolt, how do I count the number of levels I need to moved up to get the required data.
I played around the Jolt spec to convert value in "quantity" from 0 to 1

*Input*

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "product": {
        "name": "product1",
        "id": "001"
      },
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "name": "product2",
        "id": "002"
      },
      "quantity": 0
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "name": "product3",
        "id": "003"
      },
      "quantity": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

*The expected output*

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "product": {
        "name": "product1",
        "id": "001"
      },
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "name": "product2",
        "id": "002"
      },
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "name": "product3",
        "id": "003"
      },
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

*Jolt spec* with some notes for what I understand.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {                            
          "quantity": {                   
            "0": {                        
              "#1": "items.[&3].quantity" //[&3] => I move 3 levels up to items.* to get index?
            },
            "*": {
              "@(2,quantity)": "items.[&3].quantity" //@(2,quantity) => I move 2 levels up to get items.*.quantity value?
            }
          },
          "*": "items.[&1].&" //[&1] => I move 1 level up to items.* to get index?
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "quantity": "=toInteger(@(1,quantity))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Do I understand it correctly? Please advice.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I understand, you want to reflect the first `quantity` value within the `items` array to all other `quantity` values of the other objects. Then you can use these shift transformations :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "0": {
          "@": "&"
        },
        "*": {
          "@(0,product)": "&.product",
          "@(2,&1[0].quantity)": "&.quantity"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "items"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing the alternative way of resolving this in a dynamic way